# How to make a script fail when there is an error in here string?

Tags: bash, exit-status, here-document, exit, here-string

I have a script similar to this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

while read -r l; do
    echo "${l}"
done <<< "$(cat input.txt)"

echo Success
```

The command `cat input.txt` is just an example here to simplify my question.

I expected that if `input.txt` does not exist, the script would exit immediately thanks to `set -euo pipefail`. But it's not the case, instead the script ends successfully with the following output:

```
cat: input.txt: No such file or directory

Success
```

Is there a way to make the script fail as I expected?

Comment: I recommend checking beforehand if input.txt exists and would then respond accordingly.

Comment: Thanks but that's what I meant by `cat input.txt` is just an example. My actual command is long running process and I can't predict if it will fail or not. But I want my wrapping script to fail if the command fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>I understand here `cat input.txt` is a place holder for some arbitrary command. For `cat input.txt` specifically, the solution would be easy: just use input redirection from `input.txt` instead.</sup>

The exit code will be available in next expansions in the here string. For instance:

```
cat <<< "$(exit 3)$?"
```

Outputs 3. So you could do something like:

```
#! /bin/bash -
set -o nounset -o pipefail -o errexit

unset -v ret
{
  [ "$ret" -eq 0 ] || exit "$ret"
  while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line" || exit
  done
} <<< "$(cat input.txt)"${ret[1+(ret=$?)]}"
echo success
```

Which appears to work with bash 5.0 at least.

Or you could use a temporary variable:

```
#! /bin/bash -
set -o nounset -o pipefail -o errexit

output_minus_trailing_newlines=$(cat input.txt)
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
  printf '%s\n' "$line" || exit
done <<< "$output_minus_trailing_newlines"

echo success
```

In either case, if the command fails, none of its output will be processed.

You could also use a pipe and the `lastpipe` option if you don't want the loop to run in a subshell.

```
#! /bin/bash -
set -o nounset -o pipefail -o errexit
shopt -s lastpipe

cat input.txt |
  while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line" || exit
  done

echo success
```

Then the output will be processed as it comes. It's only after the pipeline exits that the shell will exit if the command failed thanks to the combination of `errexit` (`-e`) and `pipefail`. In that case, trailing empty lines are preserved.

Same using process substitution:

```
#! /bin/bash -
set -o nounset -o pipefail -o errexit

{
  pid="$!"
  while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line" || exit
  done
  wait "$pid"
} < <(cmd input.txt)

echo success
```

Or you could use a tempfile (here docs and here strings used to be implemented with temp files in bash).

```
#! /bin/bash -
set -o nounset -o pipefail -o errexit
tmp=$(mktemp)
{
  rm -f -- "$tmp"
  cat input.txt >&3
  exec 3>&-

  while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line" || exit
  done
  wait "$pid"
} 3> "$tmp" < "$tmp"

echo success
```

This way, the output is not processed if the command failed and you don't store the output (several times) in memory and the trailing empty lines are preserved.

In any case, see [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: Yes `cat input.txt` is a placeholder for a long-running application that produces logs. So in my case the first option (temporary variable) does not work because I need to "stream" the output of the command, I can't wait for it to finish to collect the output. But the pipe approach combine with the lastpipe option does work! Thanks. One important thing to note for people reading this solution is that without the lastpipe option, any variable declared or changed inside the subshell is local and dissociated from the rest of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

[[ -s input.txt ]]
while read -r l; do
    echo "${l}"
done <<< "$(cat input.txt)"

echo Success
```

Comment: Thanks but see my comment above, the `cat input.txt` part is just an example.